# Why does .toString() seem to fix an OutOfMemoryError exception for StringBuilder?

Tags: java, benchmarking, microbenchmark, jmh

I am learning how to microbenchmark things with JMH. I started with something seemingly simple: string concatenation for `StringBuilder` vs `String +=`.

From my understanding, I should make a `State` object that contains an instance of `StringBuilder` because I don't want to benchmark its constructor (nor do I want to an empty one every iteration anyway). Same goes for the `String +=` test - I want a `String` object in my `State` to be concatenated with new strings.

This is my code:

```
@State(Scope.Thread)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
public class Test {

    @State(Scope.Thread)
    public static class BenchmarkState {

        public StringBuilder    builder;
        public String           regularString;

        @Setup(Level.Iteration)
        public void setup() {
            builder         = new StringBuilder();
            regularString   = "";
        }

    }

    @Benchmark
    public String stringTest(BenchmarkState state) {
        state.regularString += "hello";
        return state.regularString;
    }

    @Benchmark
    public String stringBuilderTest(BenchmarkState state) {
        state.builder.append("hello");
        return state.builder.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws RunnerException {
        Options opt = new OptionsBuilder()
                .include(Test.class.getSimpleName())
                .forks(1)
                .timeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .mode(Mode.Throughput)
                .measurementTime(TimeValue.seconds(10))
                .build();

        new Runner(opt).run();
    }

}
```

It works, but I was thinking - I don't want to call `.toString()` at the end of every iteration. I am testing concatenation only. So I decided to remove it by just returning `null` instead.

But then, this happens during the first warmup iteration:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:124)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:448)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:136)
```

I understand that I would run out of memory pretty quickly if JMH is appending to `StringBuilder` as fast as it can, so I'm not surprised by the `OutOfMemoryError` issue. But I don't understand why does `builder.toString()` fix it.

So my questions are:

- Why does `builder.toString()` avoid an `OutOfMemoryError` issue? Doesn't `StringBuilder` still keep all the characters in memory regardless?
- Assuming that I do NOT want neither `StringBuilder`'s constructor nor its  `.toString()` method to be part of the benchmark, how do I properly write this test?

Comment: `state.regularString += "hello";` is translated (by the compiler) into `state.regularString = new StringBuilder(state.regularString).append("hello").toString();` - so it isn't clear what you're actually measuring here.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I'm just measuring which concatenation style is faster - if the compiler chooses to do that behind the scenes then that's fine.

Comment: Repeating in a loop *that* tight, and for eventually-gigantic strings, doesn't necessarily reflect normal use cases.  (You'd have to look at implementation details to tell that.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling `toString()` takes time, and generates garbage, requiring GC runs, further slowing down the code.

Since testing has a time limit, those slowdowns likely cause test to stop before it consumes all memory. If you increase the time limit, the code will likely fail with OOM even with the `toString`, it will just take a LOT longer.

Comment: So calling toString would be equivalent to telling the thread to sleep for a short interval between test runs? Interesting theory :)

Comment: @JasonSperske Sleep? No not at all. Why would you think I said that? I said that the code will do more (execute `toString`) and that it generates more garbage, requiring the JVM to collect garbage more often (i.e. *do more*), **slowing down** the code, i.e. degrading the *performance* of the code. If you monitor the CPU, you see no sleeping going on.