# StringBuilder - java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: scala, out-of-memory

The below code generates OOM error while I am only appending to the existing StringBuilder. Please explain why OOM is generated as I am not creating any new object for each recursion.

```
object BeerSong {

  val song = StringBuilder.newBuilder
  var count = 0
  def recite(start : Int, end : Int): String = {
      start match {
        case 1 => song.append(s"$start bottles of beer on the wall, $start bottles of beer.\nTake one down and pass it around, no more bottles of beer on the wall.\n")
        case 0 => song.append("No more bottles of beer on the wall, no more bottles of beer. Go to the store and buy some more, 99 bottles of beer on the wall.")
        case _ => song.append(s"$start bottles of beer on the wall, $start bottles of beer.\nTake one down and pass it around, ${start.toInt - 1} bottles of beer on the wall.\n")
      }
    count += 1
      if (count == end) {
            song.toString()
      }
      recite(start -1, end)
  }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431040/java-outofmemoryerror-with-stringbuilder
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51227953/why-does-tostring-seem-to-fix-an-outofmemoryerror-exception-for-stringbuilder
Go through these two links.

Comment: The recursive `recite()` method has no exit. There's no way for it to terminate.

Comment: Please check your logic like nowhere you are comparing ```start``` and ```end``` value to terminate the recursive logic.

Comment: where are you calling this `recite` and with what values for `start` and `end` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite you only appending to a single `StringBuilder`, internally a new array will be allocated with larger capacity on the heap when current capacity is reached. Note how error message indicates call to `Arrays.copyOf`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:124)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:448)
```

There are two possible issues with your code. One is already explained by texasbruce regarding missing recursion exit point. The other might be regarding behaviour of `count` variable. Try initialising it to equal `start` value and then decrement it

```
val start = 100
var count = start
...
count -= 1
```

instead of incrementing it

```
var count = 0
...
count += 1
```

In fact we can drop `count` variable all-together. Try the following example

```
object Example extends App {
  val song = StringBuilder.newBuilder
  def recite(start : Int, end : Int): String = {
    start match {
      case 1 => song.append(s"$start bottles of beer on the wall, $start bottles of beer.\nTake one down and pass it around, no more bottles of beer on the wall.\n")
      case 0 => song.append("No more bottles of beer on the wall, no more bottles of beer. Go to the store and buy some more, 99 bottles of beer on the wall.")
      case _ => song.append(s"$start bottles of beer on the wall, $start bottles of beer.\nTake one down and pass it around, ${start.toInt - 1} bottles of beer on the wall.\n")
    }
    if (start == end) {
      song.toString()
    }
    else recite(start - 1, end)
  }

  println(recite(100, 0))
}
```

which outputs

```
100 bottles of beer on the wall, 100 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 99 bottles of beer on the wall.
99 bottles of beer on the wall, 99 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 98 bottles of beer on the wall.
98 bottles of beer on the wall, 98 bottles of beer.
...
3 bottles of beer on the wall, 3 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 2 bottles of beer on the wall.
2 bottles of beer on the wall, 2 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 1 bottles of beer on the wall.
1 bottles of beer on the wall, 1 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, no more bottles of beer on the wall.
No more bottles of beer on the wall, no more bottles of beer. Go to the store and buy some more, 99 bottles of beer on the wall.
```

Note how we used `start == end` as exit condition.

Answer (score 2):

Your recursive function has no ending condition. You should end it when you redeem song to a string. Otherwise contrinue recursion:

```
  if (count >= end) {
        song.toString()
  }
  else {
        recite(start -1, end)
  }
```

Comment: An exception or error caused a run to abort: Java heap space 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
 at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
 at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:137)
 at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:121)
 at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:421)
 at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:136)
 at scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.scala:210)
 at BeerSong$.recite(BeerSong.scala:26)